# Conditional probability distribution (optimization)

Tags: probability

e beeing the error term
[image]

[image]

Might someone offer a derrivation, how equation 2 implies equation 3?
Isnt it the case that

P(y|x)=P(x,y)/P(x)?

Picture taken from the notes

[notes](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes1.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of $p(y|x,\theta)$ as the distribution of $y$ when $x$ is considered as a constant (i.e. it's not a random variable).

$(2)$ means that $\epsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$. This implies (using the properties of gaussian distributions) that, $\theta^Tx$ being considered constant, $\theta^T x + \varepsilon\sim\mathcal{N}(\theta^Tx,\sigma^2)$, which is exactly what $(3)$ is saying.